# Will VM server upgrade affect on my project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using GCP VM custom (2 vCPUs, 13.5 GB memory) ,, if i upgrade my VM Server Ran , Cpu or hard disk capacity will affect my existing project ?

Comment: Hi there! I am not sure to understand your question. What do you mean by `will affect my existing project` ? Like if you will face some downtime or service disruption?

Comment: To modify a Compute Engine VM instance requires stopping the instance. Then you can make changes and restart the instance.

Comment: I think these questions are more suitable to get GCP support to answer. It's fine to ping them. But most upgrades in Cloud server do require a stop.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GCP documentation, talking about the resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type): You can only change the machine type of a stopped instance. An instance is considered stopped only when the instance is in the TERMINATED state. You cannot change the machine type of a running instance.

Also mind [the billing implications](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#billing_implications):

> Each machine type is billed at a different rate, so make sure you understand the pricing implications of changing machine types. For example, an `e2-standard-2` machine type costs more than an `e2-micro` machine type.

Comment: Looks like documentation is not correct. You can change the machine type of a STOPPED instance. If the machine is terminated/deleted, you cannot really start it again.